# Logging in NLB environment

Tags: load, log4net

What is the best practice to log in network load balancer env?

How can I trace the logs in serial manner when the logs distributed in multiple machines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the best practice for logging in an enterprise system when tracing & understanding the log entries are complex is to use Query-based logging repository; not the file system.

You can use the database as a logging repository but the challenge in this case is to define the scheme appropriately to enable the developer to query the log db to understand what happens in a given execution scenario.

For good performance, You may cache the log entries and flush them to the repository when a business rule triggers. (e.g., closing billing transaction)